# web application got a error mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
select b1.blog_id, blog_name, blog_desc, b1.blog_date, blog_author, blog_img, ifnull(count(blog_cmt),0) AS blog_cmt 
from blog b1, user_blog b2"
```

I got a error in this:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"' at line 1

Comment: remove the double quotes at the end?!

Answer (score 1):

> Error #1064 means that MySQL can't understand your command. To fix it:
>
> **Read the error message**. It tells you exactly where in your command
> MySQL got confused.
>
> **Check the manual.** By comparing against what MySQL
> expected at that point, the problem is often obvious.
>
> **Check for reserved words.** If the error occurred on an object identifier, check
> that it isn't a reserved word (and, if it is, ensure that it's
> properly quoted).

You need to remove the quotes at the end and run your query. Looks like there is a typo, you intended a `;` instead.

```
select b1.blog_id, blog_name, blog_desc, b1.blog_date, blog_author, blog_img, ifnull(count(blog_cmt),0) AS blog_cmt 
from blog b1, user_blog b2;
```